# rubber fails in 'deploy:update_code'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

Trying to deploy a simple rails to staging on ec2 with rubber. Process fails with following error. Have been trying for days to find a solution but can't figure it out.

Anyone know why it fails?

```
 * 2014-03-05 15:20:13 executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /mnt/bott.ly-production /mnt/bott.ly-production/releases /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/system /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/log /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/pids"
    servers: ["staging.bott.ly"]
    [staging.bott.ly] executing command
    command finished in 1134ms
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' chmod g+w /mnt/bott.ly-production /mnt/bott.ly-production/releases /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/system /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/log /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/pids"
    servers: ["staging.bott.ly"]
    [staging.bott.ly] executing command
    command finished in 1439ms
    triggering after callbacks for `rubber:bootstrap'
  * 2014-03-05 15:20:17 executing `rubber:collectd:bootstrap'
  * executing "echo $(grep Rubber /etc/collectd/collectd.conf 2> /dev/null)"
    servers: ["staging.bott.ly"]
    [staging.bott.ly] executing command
    command finished in 1208ms
  * 2014-03-05 15:20:20 executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /mnt/bott.ly-production /mnt/bott.ly-production/releases /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/system /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/log /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/pids"
    servers: ["staging.bott.ly"]
    [staging.bott.ly] executing command
    command finished in 1187ms
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' chmod g+w /mnt/bott.ly-production /mnt/bott.ly-production/releases /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/system /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/log /mnt/bott.ly-production/shared/pids"
    servers: ["staging.bott.ly"]
    [staging.bott.ly] executing command
    command finished in 269ms
 ** updating code for bootstrap
  * 2014-03-05 15:20:24 executing `deploy:update_code'
  * getting (via checkout) revision  to C:/Users/solanmi/AppData/Local/Temp/20140305142024
    executing locally: xcopy . "C:/Users/solanmi/AppData/Local/Temp/20140305142024" /S/I/Y/Q/E
378 File(s) copied
    command finished in 4328ms
  * processing exclusions...
  * Compressing C:/Users/solanmi/AppData/Local/Temp/20140305142024 to C:/Users/solanmi/AppData/Local/Temp/20140305142024.tar.gz
    executing locally: tar czf 20140305142024.tar.gz 20140305142024
    command finished in 51ms
shell command failed with return code pid 8760 exit 53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are deploying from Windows and you may be missing the `tar` command locally or it's not in your `$PATH`

If you want to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) I recommend you install it using the it's [Setup64](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) or [Setup-x86](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe) program. I believe the `tar` package is one of the default packages that get installed. If not you can find it here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm

Comment: Hi, you're right, that was the problem... Installing bsdtar didn't solve it, since there were other errors. 

What helped a lot was using the rubber port to windows at github johnnyshields/rubber...

Comment: That's cool. So if this is satisfactory answer can you accept it ?